# Differentials to Find Maximum Error

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am asked to give the maximum error for the following:

A fluid moves through a tube of length 1 meter and radius $r=0.003±0.0002$ meters under a pressure $p=2⋅10^5±2000 $ pascals, at a rate $v=0.375⋅10^{−9} m^3$ per unit time. Use differentials to estimate the maximum error in the viscosity η given by
$η=\frac{π}{8}\frac{pr^4}{v}$.

I am having some difficulty but have found the partial derivatives with respect to p and r:

$\frac{d}{dr} = \frac{\pi pr^3}{2v}$

$\frac{d}{dp} = \frac{\pi r^4}{8v}$

I then evaluated $\frac{d}{dr}: (r, p) * 0.002 + \frac{d}{dp}: (r, p)*2000$

I got $4.523*10^7 + 2.385*10^{-17}$
This seems rather large. If you could provide some guidance that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I ended up resolving this. The computer program wanted the exact value versus the reduced approximation I gave it.